# How to respond when mouse scroll event occurs?

Tags: c++, events, opengl, scroll, mouseevent

I would like to know how to respond to a mouse scroll event in C++ only from the user's mouse wheel. I don't really care whether the user scrolls in or out as long as I catch the event that they indeed did scroll with the mouse. Can anyone show me how I can use this for an event?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the glutMouseFunc callback like this:

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
  // Wheel reports as button 3(scroll up) and   button 4(scroll down)
  if ((button == 3) || (button == 4)) 
  {
    if (state == GLUT_UP) return; // Disregard redundant GLUT_UP events
    (button == 3) ? DO_ACTION : DO_SOMETHING_ELSE;
  }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: OK and when this function is called, I call it with the glutMouseFunc function as so? glutMouseFunc(mouse);

Comment: you just need to register this callback in your main or init method. The same way you do with your display function: glutDisplayFunc(display);